# assigning function to the Ajax success event

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

The `redirect` JavaScript function work correctly without `data` parameter, but when add `data` parameter not work. how can give XML `responseText` to `redirect()` function?

Code:

```
<?php
        $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('upanel/user/update');
        echo CHtml::ajaxLink('update',$url,array(
            'method'=>'get',
            'data'=> "js:$('#user-info').serialize()",
            'datatype'=>'html',
            'success'=>'redirect(data);',
        ));
    ?>

<script>
function redirect(data){
    alert(data+' redirect');
} </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are *calling the function* instead of *assigning a function* as a callback:

```
'success'=>'redirect(data);' // calling
```

That line should change to:

```
'success'=>'redirect' // assigning callback function object
```